# Python : How to download files and write them in different directories

Tags: python, directory

I have already reviewed other posts in this regards and non of them solved my issue.
I have a script that downloads a bunch of files on daily basis from a server . I have already set the name of each file as the last part of the url. Here is my code :

```
# Grab each file.
DATE = datetime.date.today().isoformat()
for url in urls:
  r = s.get(config['base_url'] + url)
  if r.status_code == 200:
    parsed_url = urlparse(r.url)
    filename = os.path.basename(parsed_url.path,DATE)
    directory = '/data/data/data.zonefiles/CZDS'
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
      os.makedirs(directory)
    path = directory + '/' + filename + '.txt.gz'
    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(1024):
            f.write(chunk)
  else:
    sys.stderr.write("Unexpected HTTP response for URL " + url + "\n")
```

Now what I want to do is that, for each file (that is going to be downloaded on daily basis), I want a folder to be created automatically (with the same name as the file only without date) and write the output there. So basically make a separate folder for each set of files.

Currently I am getting this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "download.py", line 56, in <module>
    filename = os.path.basename(parsed_url.path,DATE)
TypeError: basename() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: What is exactly the problem? Are you unable to create a directory? Are the files not written? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: @Rik Verbeek I do not know how to make a separate directory for each set of files, and set the file names and the current file name + Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The creation of the file name seems to be wrong:

```
filename = os.path.basename(parsed_url.path,DATE)
```

`parsed_url.path` and `DATE` are 2 seperate arguments. Try something like;

```
p = parsed_url.path + "_" + DATE
filename = os.path.basename(p)
```

To create sub directories it nearly works the same way;

```
 directory = '/data/data/data.zonefiles/CZDS' + "/" + DATE
```

Comment: This works perfectly thanks. but How can I create a separate directory for each set of files? Now they are all in a same directory